# Подключение xsd-схемы к xml файлу

Tags: xml, xsd

**xml**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <students xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="students.xsd">
 <student id = "1">
   <name>Елизавета</name>
   <surname>Карпова</surname>
   <fathername>Константиновна</fathername>
   <university>СпБГУ</university>
 </student>
</students>
```

**xsd-схема**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name = "students">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name = "student">
    <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name = "name" type = "xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name = "surname" type = "xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name = "fathername" type = "xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name = "university" type = "xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Оба файла лежат в одной папке.

Ошибка:

> Сannot find declaration of element students

Элемент `students` описан, что не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что *xml* не соответствует *xsd*-схеме:

```
<student id = "1">
```

но в *xsd*-схеме у `student` нет атрибута `id`.
Схема с добавленным атрибутом `id`:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name = "students" >
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name = "student" >
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name = "name" type = "xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name = "surname" type = "xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name = "fathername" type = "xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name = "university" type = "xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```